# How to globally access properties of an image loaded in with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have loaded in an image and can access the properties within this function locally such as ball.height and width, but I need to use these properties in other functions to do calculations with. How would I access these properties since they are only locally defined currently. I can't set it as global (or at least don't know how) since in order to get the image in the first place I have to load it in with the function.

```
function drawBall() {
  var ball = new Image();
  $(ball).on('load', function() {
    ctx.drawImage(ball, xBall, yBall);
    console.log(ball.height);
  });
  ball.src = 'ball.png';
}

function ballHit() {
  // For example calculate if ball.height = canvas.height
}
```

Comment: You can store this Ball object as a global object and then access it anywhere

Comment: JavaScript is  lexically scoped. Just put the variable at a higher level and leave off the keyword `var` and don't use that `var` name as an argument in your function.

Comment: Who's calling `ballHit`? Makes a lot of difference.

Comment: @JuanMendes It will be called in another function, draw().

Comment: @VincentNguyen Well, who calls `draw()`? The point is that ideally, you'd pass the data between calls as arguments (that are maybe kept as closures) instead of using a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since the image load is a asynchronous task, you can use a callback：

```
function drawBall(callback) {
    var ball = new Image();
    $(ball).on('load', function() {
        ctx.drawImage(ball, xBall, yBall);
        console.log(ball.height);
        callback(ball.height,ball.width);
    });
    ball.src = 'ball.png';
}

drawBall(ballHit);
```

Comment: callback should probably be `callback(ball)`

Comment: yeah，it depends on the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable **globalBall** and once the image is loaded you can assign the image from the function to the global object.

```
var globalBall = new Image();
function drawBall() {
    var ball = new Image();
    $(ball).on('load', function() {
        ctx.drawImage(ball, xBall, yBall);
        console.log(ball.height);
    });
    ball.src = 'ball.png';

    globalBall = ball;
}

function ballHit() {
     if(globalball.height == canvas.height)
     {
          // Do your stuff
     }
}
```

Comment: I received error:
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'globalBall.height')

Comment: You can maybe create globalBall object of type Image.

Comment: It doesn't matter what I initialize it to, the assignment `globalBall = ball;` doesn't seem to be executing the way I expect.